# How does the 'apt satisfy' work?

Tags: apt

For the `apt` command, it has the `satisfy` option.

According with `apt --help`, it indicates

```
satisfy - satisfy dependency strings
```

and according with `man apt`, it indicates

```
   satisfy (apt-get(8))
       satisfy satisfies dependency strings, as used in Build-Depends. 
       It also handles conflicts, by prefixing an argument with "Conflicts: ".

       Example: apt satisfy "foo, bar (>= 1.0)" "Conflicts: baz, fuzz"
```

I couldn't find a tutorial through the web using this option, the "example" shown above is not clear, I mean, what is trying to solve? What is the problem that the example is solving?. Some guidance is appreciated

Answer (score 0):

In contrast to `apt-get install`, that only permit specifying a concrete package version, `apt-get satisfy` allows you to request less specific requirements.

The example you are quoting, for instance, asks for package `bar` of any version greater or equal to "1.0". And it will *remove* the `baz` and `fuzz` packages if they are installed.

The ultimate result of the command is a combination of `apt-get install` and `apt-get remove` that solves the requirements.

This is mostly useful for scripts that are expected to run in varied environments, and avoid hardcoding package versions while still maintaining confidence that a compatible baseline will be met.